# stack level too deep for a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following controller

```
class ShoppingController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @categories = Category.all
    end

end
```

with routes defined as

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :shopping, :only => [:index]
end
```

going to localhost:3000/shopping gives

```
SystemStackError at /shopping
stack level too deep
```

not able to figure out why?

==========================

## Edit

Added the Category Model as requested in comments.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    IMAGE_SIZES = {:default => [320, 200] }
    has_many    :products

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    scope :child, -> { where("parent_id <> 0") }
    scope :parent, -> { where(parent_id: 0) }
    scope :is_active, -> { where(is_active: true) }
end
```

Comment: Do you have any filers? Can you post your view code?

Comment: Please show us Category model.

Comment: The view index.html.erb would be useful aswell

Comment: There is no model. Just controller. View is blank as well..

Comment: You are trying to load `Category.all`. Show us your Category model.

Comment: The issue was caused by Category Model having a scope named parent. Prolly parent was a reserved word. corrected the issue by renaming the scope.

Comment: @QaiserWali - Didn't notice this last comment before posted answer. Please post your own answer and accept it so the question is marked as solved.

Comment: Should not answer my own question here as I got the idea after reading Marek Lipka comment on the answer as well as @Esse comment above. So if one of them answers I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not name the scope `parent`. `parent` is a method defined on a class and should not be overriden, as rails uses it to determine the table_name for your model (it needs to check whether it inherits from another ActiveRecord model, as there might be STI involved within the model).

`table_name` method is executed when model establishes connection to database. Since you override the `parent` method to return i scope, `establish_connection` will call your method, which will call `establish_connection` again and so on - infinite recurrence, hence stack level too deep error.

Rename your scope (maybe `parents`?) and all should be back to normal.

Answer (score -3):

it looks ok, but it could happen when you update some of you gems. Did you remember whether you updated some gem recently or did bundle update? If yes, you should figure out which one, and try to set previous version back.

Another problem can be in your category model code. Please provide it in order to help you.

**UPDATE**

I had that problem with gem rmagick, so after updating it stopped working and showed me 'stack level too deep' somehow. So, in order to solve it, I changed

```
gem 'rmagick'
```

to

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

Comment: I highly doubt it's about gems. The problem is probably in `Category` model.

Comment: probably you are right, but it happened to me a few times about gems, so I thought it might be a problem

Comment: Stack too deep error caused by gems conflict? How this happened?